# Since upgrade to iOS my phone does not remember position in audiobooks

Tags: ios, ringtones, audiobook

I upgraded my iPhone 3GS to iOS 6 from iOS 5 last week.

Since then the phone doesn't remember its position in audiobooks any more and most often (sometimes it remembers the position) starts at the beginning of a chapter near my last position. This happens whether or not the phone was turned off between plays.

Also, the phone forgot its ringtone and when I configured it to use my ringtone again, it suddenly started playing it very loudly despite the fact that it was set to mute. It also wouldn't stop playing it for several seconds even though I returned to the home screen and pressed the on/off button a few times.

Are these issues with iOS 6, new "features" or problems with my old phone?

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution to work:

1. Plug in your iPhone (or iPod or else, here we'll assume an iPhone) , fire iTunes
2. In iTunes, select all the songs in your Music (not in your iPhone)
3. Right-click and choose "Get Info"
4. On the window appearing, choose the "Option" Tab and select "Yes" for "Remember Playback Position"
5. Click OK to save and then synchronize your iPhone (depending on your iPhone synchronization settings, it should take over the changes from your Music to your device)